# Does Fastlane support Vision Pro?

Tags: fastlane, visionos

Does Fastlane currently (or plan to in the future) support Apple Vision Pro? Where could I read more about such support?

I cannot find evidence of such (planned) support on https://fastlane.tools. I found a [Pull Request for visionOS support](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/21574) open in the Fastlane GitHub repo, but is there a more comprehensive plan to support the Vision Pro platform? (Specifically, I want to know if I can use Fastlane to run tests in the Vision Pro Simulator.)

Answer (score 1):

It’s not currently supported. There’s a pull request open to add support which could use some feedback from the community before merging: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/21574